# AWS cli working but boto3 not finding profile

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, boto3, aws-cli

I am running a python script to connect to `AWS SSM`.

My docker-compose has this volume set up:

```
- ~/.aws/:/home/airflow/.aws
```

Boto3 Code:

```
LOCALHOST = 1
SERVICE = 'ssm'
PROFILE = 'profile3'
#File path
CURRENT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


def get_aws_client(localhost=None):
    """
    Creates boto3 aws client for any service.
    :param localhost: Parameter that enables use of roles in localhost.
    :return: aws client object
    """
    if localhost is not None:
        globals().update(LOCALHOST=localhost)
    boto_object = Boto3AwsClient(localhost=LOCALHOST, profile=PROFILE)
    aws_client = boto_object.aws_client_connect(service=SERVICE)
    return aws_client
```

It returns:

```
botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (profile3) could not be found
```

If I run:

```
docker exec -it webserver bash
```

And print

```
cat /home/airflow/.aws/credentials
cat /home/airflow/.aws/config
```

I see for credentials:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxXXXXXXXXXXX
```

For config:

```
[default]
region=eu-west-1
output=json

[profile profile3]
region=eu-west-1
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::333333333333:role/AllowBlablahblah
source_profile=default

[profile profile2]
region=eu-west-1
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::22222222222:role/AllowBliblihblih
source_profile=default

[profile profile1]
region=eu-west-1
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::1111111111111:role/AllowBlubluhbluh
source_profile=default
```

And event I can run without problem:

```
aws s3 ls
aws s3 ls --profile profile3
```

So I guess config and credentials are not really missing, and no format issue as `aws cli` is working.

I don't know what's going on here. Any idea?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.2-python3.8

ARG AIRFLOW_USER_HOME=/opt/airflow

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/"

ADD ./environtment_config/docker_src ./environtment_config/docker_src

RUN pip install -r environtment_config/docker_src/requirements.pip
```

Full docker-compose:

```
 version: '3'
    services:
      webserver:
        image: own-airflow2
        command: webserver
        ports:
          - 8080:8080
        healthcheck:
          test: [ "CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health" ]
          interval: 10s
          timeout: 10s
          retries: 5
        restart: always
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile3
        env_file:
          - ./airflow.env
        container_name: webserver
        volumes:
          - ./database_utils:/database_utils
          - ./maintenance:/maintenance
          - ./utils:/utils
          - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
          - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
          - ./airflow_sqlite:/opt/airflow
          - ~/.aws/:/home/airflow/.aws
      scheduler:
        image: own-airflow2
        command: scheduler
        healthcheck:
          test: [ "CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"' ]
          interval: 10s
          timeout: 10s
          retries: 5
        restart: always
        container_name: scheduler
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile3
        env_file:
          - ./airflow.env
        volumes:
          - ./database_utils:/database_utils
          - ./maintenance:/maintenance
          - ./utils:/utils
          - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
          - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
          - ./airflow_sqlite:/opt/airflow
          - ~/.aws/:/home/airflow/.aws
        depends_on:
          - webserver
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to say that I added env vars such as:

```
#Boto3
AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/home/airflow/.aws/config
AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=/home/airflow/.aws/credentials
```

To specify clearly which one is the correct path of the file.

Comment: Where is your `profile3` in `credentials`?

Comment: @Marcin It's not there. With my default credentials I can assume role `profile3`.
This is why I have `source_profile=default`in `config`

Comment: What is `Boto3AwsClient`? Its not part of boto3.

Comment: I notice that you are setting `AIRFLOW_USER_HOME=/opt/airflow` but placing the credentials file in `/home/airflow/.aws`. Which dir is actually the homedir for the user?

Comment: `/home/airflow/.aws` is the correct one. I tested changing `/opt/airflow` as store path and it's not working neither the `aws configure list`. On the other hand when placed: `/home/airflow/.aws` boto3 not working but `aws configure list` work.

I achieved boto3 to work adding the file in dockerfile using:

`ADD ~/.aws/credentials /home/airflow/.aws/credentials`

But i do not want to add it to the base image.